# Add New Rows To Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array which looks like the following:

```
Array (
 [class_name] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
 [zone1_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
 [zone2_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
 [zone3_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
 [zone4_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
)
```

I want to be able to add new rows which will be:

```
Array (
 [class_name] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
 [zone1_price] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
 [zone2_price] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
 [zone3_price] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
 [zone4_price] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
)
```

which would then become:

```
Array (
 [class_name] => Array (  [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
 [zone1_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
 [zone2_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
 [zone3_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
 [zone4_price] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
)
```

I am thinking I will need to use array_merge but I also think I need to separate the arrays, give them a key of some sort then combine them and add then array them.

Where would I start with something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<?php
  $first=array(
    'class_name'=>array(1,2),
    'zone1_price'=>array(1,2),  
    'zone2_price'=>array(1,2),  
    'zone3_price'=>array(1,2),  
    'zone4_price'=>array(1,2),
    );
  $second=array(
    'class_name'=>array(3,4),
    'zone1_price'=>array(3,4),  
    'zone2_price'=>array(3,4),  
    'zone3_price'=>array(3,4),  
    'zone4_price'=>array(3,4),  
    );
  $fs=sizeof($first['class_name']);
  $ss=sizeof($second['class_name']);
  foreach($first as $k => $v)
  {
    for($i=$fs;$i<$ss+$fs;$i++)
    {
      $first[$k][$i]=$second[$k][$i-$fs];
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You loop through the array with foreach, we assign the current element's key to the $key variable (in this case, each iteration key are `class_name, zone1_price, zone2_price, zone3_price, zone4_price`), we use array_push and to add the new values to the original array.

Additionally, if you'd like to assign the new values to the beginning of the array, you can use [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

```
$array = array(
  'class_name' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2),
  'zone1_price' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2),
  'zone2_price' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2),
  'zone3_price' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2),
  'zone4_price' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2),
);

foreach($array as $key => $value){
  array_push($array[$key], 3);
}
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [class_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [zone1_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [zone2_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [zone3_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [zone4_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way

```
$array = array(
            'class_name' => array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2 ),
            'zone1_price' => array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2 ),
            'zone2_price' => array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2 ),
            'zone3_price' => array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2 ),
            'zone4_price' => array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2 )
    );

$array2 = array(
            'class_name' => array( '0' => 3 ),
            'zone1_price' => array( '0' => 3 ),
            'zone2_price' => array( '0' => 3 ),
            'zone3_price' => array( '0' => 3 ),
            'zone4_price' => array( '0' => 3 )
    );

print_r(array_merge_recursive($array, $array2));
```

Comment: @Gareth This is what I would do.  Your task is exactly what this function was designed to do. Do you have any fringe cases where this is not suitable?